# How should soda made with "ginger bug" smell/taste?

Tags: yeast, fermentation, ginger, soda

I recently fermented a ginger soda using a ginger bug that I made. The bug seemed good to me - no funky mold growing on it, and it fizzled when I stirred it. The soda I made was good, but tasted extra "yeasty" and had spots on top that I couldn't differentiate between fizz or small colonies.

Is this how a fermented soda using a ginger bug should taste, and if not any suggestions on what went wrong?

**Ginger bug**

250 mL (filtered) water + 3 tablespoons grated ginger (skin on) + 3 tablespoons sugar

Contents were mixed in a jar, with a lid placed on top but not screwed shut. Left at room temperature for 5 days, with daily feedings of 1 tablespoon ginger and 1 tablespoon sugar, as well as frequent mixing.

**Soda**

120 mL ginger syrup + 240 mL filtered water + 1 tablespoon ginger bug liquid

Contents poured into swinglock bottle, left at room temperature for 2 days. Bottle was "burped" after 1 day to relieve pressure.

Answer (score 1):

if it tasted extra 'yeasty' you're probably just fermenting too far. try starting with less of the bug per liter of liquid, and stop the fermentation sooner.